# how to organize ajax search in drupal 7

Tags: ajax, drupal, search, drupal-7, drupal-views

I need a help with organization of search page in Drupal 7 with views 3 module. I have custom content type with many of content fields in it and of course I have a view for it which works pretty well. But I need also search block to work with it. Here is how it will work:
left sidebar will have ajax form with search parameters
right sidebar will have dynamic block related to my view
So when user select any parameter in block - view dynamically updates.
I tried to use contextual filters but it worked only partly, because it's not doing compare operations and it works only on page reload.

Please help me with any advices of how to organize this stuff. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the views hacks module for autosubmitting the view? http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks  Should work with ajax-enabled views.

Comment: yeah I will try, thanks. Now I just need to plan how to filter this view. I need filters like that: user enters "a" and I need to get all results that have "x" field value less than "a".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding the "Search: Search Terms" filter, edit the settings for that filter and check "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it".

[image]

Then under Advanced > Other, change "Use AJAX" to "Yes".  That should give you the basic setup.

You can also use the setting under Advanced > Exposed Form in Block to give you a block with the exposed form, which you can then position with the block configuration page.